# Order by making very slow the application using oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

In my application I need to generate the report for transaction history which is done by all clients. I have used Oracle 12c for my application. I have 300k clients. This table is related client details and transaction history table. I have written the query to generate showing transaction history per month. It returns near 20 million records.

```
SELECT C.CLIENT_ID, CD.CLIENT_NAME, ...... FROM CLIENT C, CLIENT_DETAILS CD, 
TRANSACTION_HISTORY TH
--Condition part
ORDER BY C.CLIENT_ID
```

These 3 tables have right indexes which is working fine. But when fetching data using order by to showing customers in order this query takes 8 hours to execute the batch process.

I have analysed the cost of the query. Cost is 80085. But when I remove the order by from query the cost became to 200. So that I have removed the order by as of now. But I need to show the customers by order. I cannot use the limit. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: How many rows are in the transaction_history table? I suspect there are lots (billions, maybe?) and that the table isn't partitioned, if the query is taking over 8 hours to run with an order by. It's possible (depending on what your "condition part" that you might get some benefit from partitioning. Please edit your question to include the execution plans of the query with and without the order by clause - that may shed some light on the matter.

Comment: There is a partition for every 3 months. Now Transaction history having near to 4 crore records. Sorry Boneist. Unfortunately i cannot give the execution plans. Am asking this from mobile. I have some restrictions in my office

Comment: One crore is ten million.

Comment: @Varman The cost column is not valuable for SQL tuning, because the "best" execution plan may not be the one with the lowest cost. You can have a look at [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_execution_plan_cost_column.htm)

Comment: @Varman You can absolutely give the execution plans despite restrictions in your office if you modify the table/view/index/etc names to something generic. From a mobile would be a tad difficult, though! *{:-) There isn't really enough information in your question to be able to help you, sadly. We can speculate, but it's unlikely to be of use to you. Please update your question when you can to include the execution plans and also the conditions in your query - you don't have to use the same names as your actual tables etc, but they should match those in the execution plan.

Comment: Let me update here once available boneist

Comment: ORDER BY would use sort buffers and then temporary segments to sort your result set, and the ORDER BY does not change which indexes are selected in your explain plan. It's possible your tempseg is missing or small. Is this your 12c database? Are you able to select * from dba_temp_free_space?

Answer (score 0):

you can try indexing the client id in the table, which would speed up the performance of the table to fetch the data in some order.

you can use the link for the reference: [link](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by)

Hope this would help you